# How to get taxonomy id by it's name? Drupal 9

Tags: drupal

While creating a node, I am required to input entity reference ID in the **field_tag**.
The problem is that I only have entity reference name.

How can I get the term id (tid) for a taxonomy term from the term name?

I'm very surprised that I can't find an answer anywhere, since this seems to me to be a simple, basic question.

```
      $node = Node::create([
        'type'  => 'news',
        'title' => $naslov,
        'body'  => $tekst,
        'field_tag'  => // Taxonomy reference name is "ostalo", I need it's ID here

        ],
      );
      $node->save();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name* function might be deprecated.
Check [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name/9.3.x).

Consider using something like:

```
$vid = 'tags';
$term_name = 'ostalo';

$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
            ->loadByProperties([
                    'vid' => $vid,
                    'name' =>$term_name,
                ]);

foreach ($terms as $term) {

    $term_id = $term->id();

}
```

Comment: You are right. These drupal versions differ a lot by functions and that's what got me confused. v9 still lacks some answers. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can use the [taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name/9.2.x) function.</s>

eg.
`$tids = taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name('ostalo');`

**EDIT..**
Woops, didn't realize I was looking at an older version of the api. As Balde Binos says, it's deprecated. His answer is the correct one.